# Why is applicationState being returned as nil?

Tags: ios, objective-c, application-state

I'm trying to check the application state of my iOS app, but when I check

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState
```

I'm getting nil. I checked that [UIApplication sharedApplication] is not nil. I'm basically just checking whether or not the screen is on, so I'm just checking the result of the following:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive
```

Any idea why I'm getting nil returned?

Comment: `UIApplicationState` is an `enum` so `nil` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Perhaps you are confusing `UIApplicationStateActive` (value `0`) with `nil`?

Comment: @trojanfoe I'm debugging and after the line

    'UIApplicationState *applicationState = [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState;'

I query

    'po applicationState'

and get '$4 = 0x00000000 <nil>'

Comment: `UIApplicationState` is not a class; it's an enum. `UIApplicationStateActive` == 0, so that makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK your code is incorrect (I'm surprised it compiled):

```
UIApplicationState *applicationState = [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState;
```

Should be:

```
UIApplicationState applicationState = [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState;
```

(it's an `enum` not an object).

Comment: Thanks, I'm a little unfamiliar with Objective-C enums.

Comment: @ferson2020 Yeah the only way to tell if an object is being returned or an `enum` or `typedef` is to look for the pointer operator (`*`).